# Gradient Texture Map to Ring Inset

Tags: texturing

I am hoping this is a simple question....

1. I have a Gradient Texture,
2. I have a hollow circle mesh extruded to a ring,
3. I have an outside/outset and an inside/inset to the ring.

I am trying to map the gradient texture in a clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation to just the inset face, so that if you cut the ring and laid it flat the gradient would just be a simple left to right flat gradient.

Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cycles render engine you could easily use a gradient texture as illustrated in the node setup bellow, <s>though I am not sure it can be animated, as color ramp handles can't be keyframed as far as I know.</s>

Has suggested by timaroberts, you can then animate this as desired by keyframing the position of the Color ramp handles in the *Pos* value.

[image]

[image: Nodes]

Otherwise your best bet is probably unwrapping your mesh and animating the UV coordinates. You could then use a regular linear gradient with it.

Comment: To animate a color ramp, add a keyfame to the *pos value* of the color stop.

Comment: Hey nice one didn't know that. Always learning something new, I love BSE. Thanks for the tip, I'll update the answer.